# Extract just the argument type list from decltype(someFunction)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype, variadic

I have a variadic template that represents a list of parameters for a function, eg:

```
void myFunc (int,int,std::string) { }
template<typename... Args> class MyTemplateClass { };
...
MyTemplateClass<int,int,std::string> myConcrete; // for use with myFunc later
```

Is there any way I can extract just the argument types from decltype(func) to save having to write them manually, eg:

```
MyTemplateClass<something_like_decltype(myFunc)> myConcrete;
```

ie decltype in this case would give me "void(int,int,string)" but is there a way of extracting just the "int,int,string" part for use in the variadic template?

Note: I must use the variadic template method because within the template it performs processing on each argument type in turn.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following should work:

```
template<template<typename...> class C,typename T>
struct apply_args;

template<template<typename...> class C,typename R,typename... Args>
struct apply_args<C, R(Args...) >
{
    typedef C<Args...> type;
};

typedef apply_args<MyTemplateClass,decltype(myFunc)>::type MyConcrete;
MyConcrete myConcrete;
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's an alternative (borrowing ideas from [Daniel Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073257/daniel-frey)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871165/1137388)) using a function template rather than a class template:

```
template <template<typename...> class C, typename R, typename... Args>
C<Args...> apply_args(R(Args...));

void f(int, bool);

using MyPair = decltype(apply_args<std::pair>(f)); // = std::pair<int, bool>
MyPair myPair{42, false};
```

**Edit**: Comments on my solution x [Daniel Frey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871165/1137388):

Mine saves typing. His is more idiomatic. Indeed, in C++ metaprogramming a
"function" (or a meta-function) that takes types and return a type is
(generally) implemented as a template classe whose member `type` gives the
return. For this reason, I prefer his solution.