# Does C++11, 14 or 17 provide a way to get just the arguments out of a decltype()?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-argument-deduction

This question is very similar to: "[Extract just the argument type list from decltype(someFunction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870918/extract-just-the-argument-type-list-from-decltypesomefunction)".  I'm not sure the answers there work for what I'm intending though.  I'd like to be able to create a template function that deduces the type of its runtime arguments based on the type of a function pointer template argument (*whistles*).

For an example use case, let's say I want to instrument straight C POSIX file I/O using a shim library loaded with LD_PRELOAD.  I could write separate wrappers for fopen, fread, fwrite, fclose...  If all of those wrappers do similar stuff though, wouldn't it be nice if I could define a template that captures the common behavior?

Partial example NOT using templates that demonstrates how much boilerplate is involved:

```
extern "C" {

FILE *(*real_fopen)(const char *, const char *) = NULL;
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *returned_file;

    if (real_fopen == NULL) {
        real_fopen = ((FILE *)(const char *, const char *))dlsym("fopen", RTLD_NEXT);
    }

    ... do pre-call instrumentation ...
    returned_file = real_fopen(path, mode);
    ... do post-call instrumentation ...

    return returned_file;
}

int (*real_fclose)(FILE *) = NULL;
int fclose(FILE *fp)
{
    int retval;

    if (real_fclose == NULL) {
        real_fclose = ((int)(FILE *))dlsym("fclose", RTLD_NEXT);
    }

    ... do pre-call instrumentation ...
    retval = real_fclose(path, mode);
    ... do post-call instrumentation ...

    return retval;
}

... additional definitions following the same general idea ...

}
```

We can save some code using a variadic template function:

```
template <typename func_ptr_type, func_ptr_type real_func_ptr,
    const char *dl_name, typename... Args>
std::result_of<func_type> wrap_func(Args... args)
{
    std::result_of<func_type> retval;
    if (real_func_ptr == NULL) {
        real_func_ptr = (func_ptr_type)dlsym(dl_name, RTLD_NEXT);
    }

    ... do pre-call instrumentation ...
    retval = real_func_ptr(args...);
    ... do post-call instrumentation ...

    return retval;
}

FILE *(*real_fopen)(const char *, const char *) = NULL;
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    return wrap_func<decltype(real_fopen), real_fopen, "fopen", const char *, const char *>(path, mode);
}

int (*real_fclose)(FILE *) = NULL;
int fclose(FILE *fp)
{
    return wrap_func<decltype(real_fclose), real_fclose, "fclose", FILE *>(fp);
}
```

There's gotta be some way we can avoid passing all of those redundant types in the list of template parameters though.  What I would like to do that I haven't found valid syntax for yet (presumes the existence of something I'll call std::arguments_of that's sort of like the opposite of std::result_of):

```
template <typename func_ptr_type, func_ptr_type real_func_ptr,
    const char *dl_name, std::arguments_of(func_ptr_type)>
std::result_of<func_type> wrap_func(std::arguments_of(func_ptr_type)... args)
{
    std::result_of<func_type> retval;
    if (real_func_ptr == NULL) {
        real_func_ptr = (func_ptr_type)dlsym(dl_name, RTLD_NEXT);
    }

    ... do pre-call instrumentation ...
    retval = real_func_ptr(args...);
    ... do post-call instrumentation ...

    return retval;
}

FILE *(*real_fopen)(const char *, const char *) = NULL;
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    return wrap_func<decltype(real_fopen), real_fopen, "fopen">(path, mode);
}

int (*real_fclose)(FILE *) = NULL;
int fclose(FILE *fp)
{
    return wrap_func<decltype(real_fclose), real_fclose, "fclose">(fp);
}
```

Is there a valid way to do this in C++11, 14 or 17?  How, or if not, why not?

Comment: There are several other problems with your design. A string literal cannot be used as a template argument, nor a non-constant-expression like `real_fclose`. And you can't assign to a template parameter.

Comment: I could see where it would be more idiomatic to have real_func_ptr as a parameter to wrap_func the function rather than the template.  It seems to work the way I've got it with Intel C++ 15 and -std=c++11 though.  Is ICPC 15 just letting me skirt the rules here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use partial specialization:

```
template <typename func_ptr_type, func_ptr_type real_func_ptr,
    const char *dl_name>
struct Wrapper;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args, Ret (*real_func_ptr)(Args...),
    const char *dl_name>
struct Wrapper<Ret(*)(Args...), real_func_ptr, dl_name>
{
    static Ret func(Args... args) { /* ... */ }
};
```

The wrinkle is that because you can't partially specialize functions you need to use a class template - here `Wrapper`.

Answer (score 3):

You might use the function pointer to deduce the return and argument types:

```
#include <iostream>

FILE *fake_fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    std::cout << "Library Function: " << path << " " << mode << "\n";
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename Result, typename... Arguments>
Result dl_wrap(
    const char* dl_name,
    Result (*&function)(Arguments...), // Reference to function pointer
    Arguments... arguments)
{
    function = (Result (*)(Arguments...))fake_fopen; //dlsym
    return function(arguments ...);
}

FILE *(*real_fopen)(const char *, const char *) = nullptr;
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    return dl_wrap("fopen", real_fopen, path, mode);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fopen("Hello", "World");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your template solution, `Args` can be deduced, so

```
return wrap_func<decltype(real_fopen), real_fopen, "fopen">(path, mode);
```

is enough.